# Linked tree built from (n) leaves

Tags: recursion, tree, kotlin

Firstly, here is the relevant code. It is written in kotlin.

```
package com.minz.tournaments

import kotlin.math.ceil
import kotlin.math.log2
import kotlin.math.pow

@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
class TournamentTree(initialParticipants: Map<Int, Participant>) {
private var rootNode: ParticipantNode
private val participantMap = initialParticipants

val participants: List<Participant>
    get() = participantMap.values.toList()

private val numParticipants: Int
    get() = participants.size
val numByes: Int
    get() = getNextPowerOf2(numParticipants) - numParticipants
private var currentMatches = ArrayDeque<Match>(numParticipants)
private val numNodes: Int
    get() = (numParticipants * 2) - 1
private val height: Int
    get() = ceil(log2(numNodes + 1f)).toInt()

fun getRounds(): List<List<Participant>> {
    val queue = ArrayDeque<ParticipantNode>(numParticipants)
    queue.addLast(rootNode)

    var depth = 1
    var numNodes = 1

    val rounds = ArrayList<ArrayList<Participant>>(height)

    for (i in 0 until height) {
        rounds.add(ArrayList())
    }

    while (queue.size > 0) {
        val temp = queue.removeFirst()
        rounds[height - depth].add(temp.participant)

        if (temp.left != null) {
            queue.addLast(temp.left)
        }
        if (temp.right != null) {
            queue.addLast(temp.right)
        }

        if (++numNodes == 2f.pow(depth).toInt()) {
            depth++
        }
    }

    return rounds
}

fun getRoundsFlat(): List<Participant> {
    val queue = ArrayDeque<ParticipantNode>(numParticipants)
    queue.addLast(rootNode)

    val rounds = ArrayList<Participant>(numNodes)
    while (queue.size > 0) {
        val temp = queue.removeFirst()
        rounds.add(temp.participant)

        if (temp.left != null) {
            queue.addLast(temp.left)
        }
        if (temp.right != null) {
            queue.addLast(temp.right)
        }
    }

    return rounds
}

private fun getNextEmptyParticipantLO(participantNode: ParticipantNode): ParticipantNode? {
    val queue = ArrayDeque<ParticipantNode>(numParticipants)

    queue.addLast(participantNode)

    while (queue.size > 0) {
        val temp = queue.removeFirst()

        if (temp.left != null) {
            queue.addLast(temp.left)
            if (temp.right != null) {
                queue.addLast(temp.right)
                if ((!temp.left.participant.isEmpty) && (!temp.right.participant.isEmpty) && (!temp.hasLinkedMatch)) {
                    return temp
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null
}

fun getNextMatches(): List<Match> {
    val emptyParticipantNode = getNextEmptyParticipantLO(rootNode)

    while (emptyParticipantNode != null) {
        emptyParticipantNode.left?.participant?.let lit@{ left ->
            emptyParticipantNode.right?.participant?.let { right ->
                if (left.isEmpty || right.isEmpty)
                    return@lit

                val match = Match(left, right)
                emptyParticipantNode.linkedMatch = match
                currentMatches.addFirst(match)
            }
        }
    }

    return currentMatches.toList()
}

init {
    require(initialParticipants.size > 1) {
        "The amount of participants in the tournament must be greater than 1"
    }

    val participants = ArrayDeque<ParticipantNode>(numParticipants)

    initialParticipants.forEach { (_, participant) ->
        participants.addLast(ParticipantNode(participant))
    }

    while (participants.size > 1) {
        val first = participants.removeFirst()
        val second = participants.removeFirst()

        participants.addLast(ParticipantNode(Participant(), second, first))
    }

    rootNode = participants.removeFirst()
}

private fun getNextPowerOf2(number: Int): Int {
    var num = number - 1
    num = num or (num shr 1)
    num = num or (num shr 2)
    num = num or (num shr 4)
    num = num or (num shr 8)
    num = num or (num shr 16)
    num++
    return num
    }
}
```

This is a tree that is generated given n leaves. The Participant class is a data class containing a name string that is empty by default. The ParticipantNode class is a class that contains a participant, and 2 references to other nodes, "left" and "right". These references can be null.

I think there are aspects of this design that might have a bit to be desired, and I'd like another look at it before I go ahead and build on top of this with the rest of my application. Thanks!

Comment: Great first post :)

Comment: How does the `while` in `getNextMatches` work? I mean, once `emptyParticipantNode` is not null, it doesn't change right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a problem with the code. It should be an if statement instead of a while loop.